# Get type definition of a constructor at build time in dart

Tags: dart

Imagine I have a class like this

```
Class Foo {
   String bar;
   Foo(this.bar);
}
```

And we can create a function that takes in this constructor like this:

```
(Foo Function(String) constructor) test => constructor('hello');
test(Foo.new);
```

This is verbose though (Imagine if I had a constructor with many arguments) - Is there anyway I can obtain an alias to the foo constructor? Something like:

```
(TypeOf<Foo.new> constructor) test => constructor('hello');
test(Foo.new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [typedef's](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) are what you are looking for?

They are a way to give an alias (*nickname*) to a type. In your case, the type to alias would be:

```
Foo Function(String);
```

You can give it a new name with:

```
typedef FooConstructor = Foo Function(String);
```

This way you can use it later with:

```
(FooConstructor constructor) test => constructor('hello');
```

For more info, read the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs), or check the [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-use-the-legacy-typedef-syntax) on that topic.

Comment: No, I am aware of typedefs. I'm asking to "get" the typedef of a function without writing it myself.